# How to avoid zombie process with envoy.connect?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, python-envoy

I just discovered the 'envoy' module, a wrapper for python subprocess made by the creator of requests.

I have a problem with the 'connect' function: everytime I use it, it results in a zombie process and I can't get the status_code or the result.

```
c=envoy.connect("ls -al")
c.status_code == None
 True
```

If I do a '*ps -ef|grep thepid*', I get a 'defunct' pid.

I can kill the zombie by doing a os.wait() or a c._process.wait(), but I can't get the result (stdout) of my command...

Any idea?

Comment: After a deeper look at my problem, I think it's platform/pythonVersion related: I'm using python 2.6 on Solaris10 (x86) and event the testcases given with envoy doesn't work.

c = envoy.connect("sleep 1")
time.sleep(2)
self.assertEqual(c.status_code, 0)

==> Keeps having a zombie proc and a 'None' status_code.

Unfortunately, I have no way to upgrade python, since it depends on an other team.

I'm doing some tests on a linux machine...

Answer (score 1):

In your case you should use the `run()` method

As envoy documentation recommends:

```
r = envoy.run(cmd)
print r.status_code, r.std_out
```

But in case you want the command run asynchronously you can use `connect()` **followed by `block()`**

Once `block()` is called, return code becomes available. But block() would block your program so the logic should be.

```
c1=envoy.connect(cmd1)
c2=envoy.connect(cmd2)
c3=envoy.connect(cmd3)
... more staff ...
c1.block()
print c1.status_code
```

Comment: run() works fine, but I wanted to use connect() to have non-blocking processes.
My script has to launch tenth of commands. The 'ls -al' was just here for example purpose. The actual command take almost one minute to send a result...

Comment: Yes, I understand. Fixed the answer, look if it helps.

Comment: +1 for `.block()`. `del c1` should also lead to reaping the zombie process.

Answer (score 1):

> but I can't get the result (stdout) of my command...

[`ConnectedCommand`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/envoy/blob/a02ad4c7e1021e4443e3e4edc87715182c23f85f/envoy/core.py#L100) (the type returned by `envoy.connect()`) doesn't seem to be ready. In particular, the command can deadlock if it receives/generates enough (depending on platform) input/output.

In addition to calling `c.block()` that also works for alive processes; you could remove all references to the command and use `del c` to reap the zombie. If subprocesses are not dead; they won't be reaped until a cleanup method is run on start of the next subprocess (it depends on the implementation).

If `envoy.run()` capabilities are not enough for your task; you could use `subprocess` module directly. For example, to pass input to several processes and collect corresponding results; you could use `ThreadPool` and `.communicate()` method:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def process(child_input):
    child, input = child_input # unpack arguments
    return child.communicate(input)[0], child.returncode # get the result


# define input to be pass to subprocesses
params = b"a b c".split()

# start subprocesses (the command is just an example, use yours instead)
children = [Popen("( echo -n {0}; sleep {0}; cat )".format(len(params) - i),
                  shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
            for i in range(len(params))]

# use threads to wait for results in parallel
pool = ThreadPool(len(params))
for output, returncode in pool.imap_unordered(process, zip(children, params)):
    if returncode == 0:
       print("Got %r" % output)
```

The less child sleeps the sooner its result is available to the parent regardless of the original order.

No zombies and It won't deadlock if input/output exceed pipe buffers.